# Dropdown links not working only for Android Chrome combination

Tags: android, html, css

The test site is up here. http://www.ssbmn.com/new/test.php

Any browser works except for Android(Chrome) it does nothing when touching a link. I cannot figure this out.

I also have the code here. http://jsfiddle.net/bigdessert/fL3Jg/

I think it has something to do with this code:

```
     .dropdown_1column{
        position:absolute;
        left:-999px; /* Hides the drop down */
    }
    #menu li:hover .dropdown_1column{
        left:0;
        top:53px;
    }
```

If I remove both those so the drop menu is always shown it works fine.

Please remember, the only thing this doesn't work on is chrome and only on android.

Comment: I don't see any code to help with here. Please post your code or the section of your code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: I can see the problem in Chrome (on Nexus7) on the drop-down menu links not working, but there's nothing obvious in remote debugging going wrong. Do you have a small sample of just one of the menu items  (as I suspect there is something in the way the popup is happening) that may be confusing things

Comment: while you added nice information, please explain what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: The dropdown links are not clickable from android chrome browser. All other browsers are ok.

Comment: Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem with the latest version of chrome for android. If you uninstall the updates from chrome, css menus work. If you install the latest updates, it doesn't work.

I haven't as yet found a workaround for this.